# C# cast child to parent

Tags: c#

Hello I have this class:

```
class A{
 public string P1{get; set;}
 public string P2{get; set;}
 ...
 public string PX{get; set;}
}
```

This class is in DLL and i don't need to change it. But I would like to add some property, so I created class B:

```
class B : A{
  public bool IsSelected{get;}
}
```

It's ok, but now I would like to convert class B to A (without `IsSelected` property):

```
B b = new B();
A a = (A)b;
```

Variable `a` has `IsSelected`. Is is way how to do it? Or how to design this model better?

Comment: _"Is is way how to do it?"_ I don't know what you are trying to do. Since `B` has `IsSelected` you can't access it without casting if you have an `A`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Variable `a` has `IsSelected` **but** you can not access `IsSelected` through variable `a`.

Comment: You don't even need the typecast: `A a = b;` is OK. Now you have a parent-typed reference to a child instance.

Comment: @Rango Object A is being send using WCF and when contains `IsSelected` property,    it can not be sent. In application I need `A + IsSelected` but when I need send it, A must be without `IsSelected`

Comment: @bluray: create another model which maps from `A` and has `IsSelected`. I would not use inheritance for it

Comment: You'd better use the naming **Base** and **Derived** class, parent/childs are normally used for tree structures. The title confused me.

Comment: @blueray Try applying the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute on your `IsSelected` property. This tells the WCF serializer to skip the field. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: create interface(IX) that has property <IsSelected > and inherit B from A and IX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to decide that not B is-an A but B has-an A :

```
class B 
{
  public A A { get;  }
  public bool IsSelected{get;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Object A is being send using WCF and when contains IsSelected property, it can not be sent. In application I need A + IsSelected but when I need send it, A must be without IsSelected

You can tell the WCF serializer to ignore the field by applying the [`IgnoreDataMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute:

```
class B : A{
  [IgnoreDataMember]
  public bool IsSelected{get;}
}
```